# PC crashses when I enable VT-X (Virtualization technology) intel i5-3450

Tags: windows, crash

When I boot up and go to BIOS and enable Virtulization Technology and save settings, as soon as I save & exit my PC turns of and turns on, then turns off again and then turns on and boots windows and VT-X is disabled.

So it seems as if when I turn it on it crashes and then it tries another time with VT-X enabled but crashes again and then disables it and turns on like it normally would, but that means I can't use VT-X and I would really like to because VirtualBox requires it on some Operating systems.

I  hope someone has a solution or some guidelines!

System Info:
HP Pavilion Desktop PC
Windows 10 Home
Intel i5-3450
Radeon RX550

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately this is a site for software programming questions - not hardware issues

Comment: My mistake, I thought it was alright to ask questions like this, I'll ask somewhere else.
Thanks!